# TypeScript additionning number return high float

Tags: types, typescript, numbers

I've an issue with TypeScript. When i addition two number (*15.99* and *5.00*)
i get *20.9900000000002* in result.

Here my declaration :

```
 private difference: number;
 private prixReference : number;
 private max: number;
[...]
 this.prixReference = 15.99;
 this.difference = 5.00;
 this.max = this.prixReference + this.difference;
```

**Debugger** :

[image: debugger values]

Any idea ?

Comment: [Enjoy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally floating point number in CPUs cannot precisely represent decimal fractions as the CPU representation is based on binary format.

So basically `0.5` is fine as it results into `1/2` or `2^-1`, `0.25` similarly results into `2^-2` etc. But `0.1` result into `1/10` which is not possible to represent as (negative) power of `2`.

As a result any fraction which is not power of `2` or their additions always results into some rounding which occurs at the last digit of floating number mantissa. Javascript usually uses `double` type which has precision up to 53 bits (which is about 16 decimal digits) - see [double format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).